# Determine MSI that was used to install a Windows service

Tags: windows-installer, wmi

Is there a way using Win32_Class and C# combined maybe with ManagementBaseObject to determine the MSI that was used to install a Windows service? Or some other means (preferably using C#)?

I need to iterate over all the current services and ask (some entity...MSI database(s)?) who installed this service?

Iterating over all the services I can do using ManagementObjectSearcher query on Win32_Service WMI class, but I don't see any way to tie back to the MSI (if there was one) used to deliver the service. I know not all services are installed using MSIs, but for the ones that are, I'd like to document those for a report I am to produce.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Deja vu, you've already asked this question.

Comment: Ugh...I need sleep, I think...sorry.